# Which actor/actress has played the largest number of distinct actual persons in tv / cinema?

Tags: acting

I was wondering which actors / actresses have played an unsual large number of *different* actual (historical) persons in during their entire career.

- Multiple appearances as the same character do only count once. So playing Cleopatra in 15 movies will count as one role, but playing 15 different persons in one movie as 15.
- It doesn't matter what genre or wether the plot is fictionalized if the person is somewhat recognizable. 
  So e.g. film versions of Shakespeare's king dramas, musicals or "Abraham Lincoln Vampire Hunter" will be accepted.
- Fictional characters obviously modelled after historical persons will *not* be accepted.
- Docudramas or voice acting for animated movies will be accepted.
- The amount of screentime or dialogue does not matter. Cameos or silent roles will be accepted.

Comment: ...And I'm actually racking my brain to think of a historical figure that Meryl Streep *didn't* play. ;)

Comment: The thing is, there are many impressionists and comedians that might play zillions of famous people in sketch shows. Does that count?

Comment: Hmm, good point. But I was rather thinking of feature films. Mainly the classical biopic / costume drama stuff.

Comment: Well, you can always fine-tune it a bit more, if that's what you're after.

Comment: What does your research show? Why is it that you can't find it on the internet by Googling?

Comment: @Rathony Well, *I* sure couldn't... It's actually pretty hard to answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming you're ruling out impressionists, [Christopher Plummer](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0001626/) must be a very serious contender with (at least) **32 portrayals** of famous people throughout his 63-year career in film and television. [And I say "at least" because 1. *He's still acting* and 2. I might've missed some.] Here are all the roles, in reverse chronological order:

1. [**Kaiser Wilhelm II**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wilhelm_II,_German_Emperor), [*The Exception*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt4721124/) (2016)
2. [**Justice John Marshall Harlan II**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_Marshall_Harlan_II), [*Muhammad Ali's Greatest Fight*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2061756/) (2013)
3. [**Actor John Barrymore**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_Barrymore), [*Barrymore*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2033952/) (2011)
4. [**Author Leo Tolstoy**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leo_Tolstoy), [*The Last Station*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0824758/) (2009)
5. [**Julius Caesar**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Julius_Caesar), [*Caesar and Cleopatra*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1318049/) (2009)
6. [**Captain Christopher Newport**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Christopher_Newport), [*The New World*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0402399/) (2005)
7. [**Cardinal Bernard Francis Law**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernard_Francis_Law), [*Our Fathers*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0421108/) (2005)
8. [**Aristotle**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aristotle), *[Alexander](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0346491/)* (2004)
9. [**Canadian ambassador John Watkins**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_Watkins_(Canadian_diplomat)), [*Agent of Influence*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0307934/) (2002)
10. [**F. Lee Bailey**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/F._Lee_Bailey), [*American Tragedy*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0250135/) (2000)
11. [**David Patrick Maxwell Fyfe, 1st Earl of Kilmuir**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/David_Maxwell_Fyfe,_1st_Earl_of_Kilmuir), [*Nuremberg*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0208629/) (2000)
12. [**Mike Wallace**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mike_Wallace), [*The Insider*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0140352/)  (1999)
13. [**Franklin D. Roosevelt**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Franklin_D._Roosevelt), [*Winchell*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0149380/) (1998)
14. [**Canadian politician George Hees**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/George_Hees), [*The Arrow*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0118641/) (1997)
15. [**Photographer Alfred Stieglitz**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alfred_Stieglitz), [*A Marriage: Georgia O'Keeffe and Alfred Stieglitz*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0102409/) (1991)
16. [**Charles Hanbury Williams**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charles_Hanbury_Williams), [*Young Catherine*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0103311/) (1991)
17. [**Vladimir Nabokov**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vladimir_Nabokov), [*Nabokov on Kafka*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0192347/) (1989)
18. [**Cyrano de Bergerac**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyrano_de_Bergerac), [*Parade of Stars*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1556683/combined) (1983) and [*Cyrano De Bergerac*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0224818/) (1962)
19. [**Col. Herbert Kappler**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Herbert_Kappler), [*The Scarlet and the Black*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0086251/) (1983)
20. [**Reginald Claypoole Vanderbilt**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reginald_Claypoole_Vanderbilt), [*Little Gloria... Happy at Last*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0084258/) (1982)
21. [**Canadian PM John A. Macdonald**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_A._Macdonald), [*Riel*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0079810/) (1979)
22. [**Herod Antipas**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Herod_Antipas), [*Jesus of Nazareth*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0075520/) (1977)
23. [**Rudyard Kipling**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rudyard_Kipling), [*The Man Who Would Be King*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0073341/) (1975)
24. [**Archduke Franz Ferdinand**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Archduke_Franz_Ferdinand_of_Austria), [*The Day That Shook the World*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0073660/) (1975)
25. [**Arthur Wellesley, Duke of Wellington**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arthur_Wellesley,_1st_Duke_of_Wellington), [*Witness to Yesterday*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0168437/combined) (1974) and [*Waterloo*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0066549/) (1970)
26. [**Atahuallpa**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atahualpa), [*The Royal Hunt of the Sun*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0064907/) (1969)
27. [**Erwin Rommel**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erwin_Rommel), [*The Night of the Generals*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0062038/) (1967)
28. [**WWII spy Eddie Chapman**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eddie_Chapman), [*Triple Cross*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0061647/) (1966)
29. [**Captain Georg von Trapp**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Georg_von_Trapp), [*The Sound of Music*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0059742/) (1965)
30. [**Commodus**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commodus), [*The Fall of the Roman Empire*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0058085/) (1964)
31. [**Justice Oliver Wendell Holmes Jr.**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oliver_Wendell_Holmes_Jr.), [*Our American Heritage: Autocrat and Son*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1123304/combined) (1960)
32. [**Robert Carr, 1st Earl of Somerset**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robert_Carr,_1st_Earl_of_Somerset), *[The King's Bounty](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0622555/)* (1955)

Answer (score 1):

[Tom Hanks](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0000158/?ref_=tt_cl_t6) is a good canditate, he played the following real life figures:

Jim Lovell in [Apollo 13](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0112384/?ref_=nm_flmg_act_52)

Charlie Wilson in [Charlie Wilson's War](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0472062/?ref_=nm_flmg_act_29)

Captain Richard Phillips in [Captain Phillips](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1535109/?ref_=nm_flmg_act_13)

James B. Donovan in [Bridge of Spies](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt3682448/?ref_=nm_flmg_act_8)

Chesley Sullenberger in [Sully](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt3263904/?ref_=nm_flmg_act_4)

The movie [Catch Me If You Can](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0264464/?ref_=nm_flmg_act_40) is also based on real life events, but according to [IMDb](http://www.imdb.com/character/ch0004040/bio), his role Carl Hanratty is a composite of several real life figures:

> "Note: For the film "Catch Me If You Can," the character of Carl
>   Hanratty is a composite of several FBI figures who were instrumental
>   in finding and catching Frank Abagnale, JR."

Another canditate is [Richard Burton](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0000009/) for his roles in the following movies:

[Alexander the Great](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0048937/?ref_=nm_flmg_act_63), [Cleopatra](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0056937/?ref_=nm_flmg_act_48), [Becket](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0057877/?ref_=nm_flmg_act_46), [Anne of the Thousand Days](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0064030/?ref_=nm_flmg_act_29), [The Assassination of Trotsky](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0068226/?ref_=nm_flmg_act_23), [Sutjeska](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0070758/?ref_=nm_flmg_act_19), [The Gathering Storm](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0071536/?ref_=nm_flmg_act_14), [Wagner](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0085107/?ref_=nm_flmg_act_3)

Or [Anthony Hopkins](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0000164/?ref_=ttfc_fc_cl_t24) for his roles in the following movies:

[The Great Inimitable Mr. Dickens](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0065796/?ref_=nm_flmg_act_122), [Young Winston](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0069528/?ref_=ttfc_fc_tt), [Lloyd George](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0070330/?ref_=nm_flmg_act_113), [The Lindbergh Kidnapping Case](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0074801/?ref_=nm_flmg_act_100), [Victory at Entebbe](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0075391/?ref_=nm_flmg_act_99), [A Bridge Too Far](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0075784/?ref_=nm_flmg_act_97), [The Bunker](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0082114/?ref_=nm_flmg_act_91), [The Bounty](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0086993/?ref_=nm_flmg_act_84), [Chaplin](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0103939/?ref_=nm_flmg_act_61), [Nixon](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0113987/?ref_=nm_flmg_act_52), [Amistad](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0118607/?ref_=nm_flmg_act_48), [Alexander](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0346491/?ref_=nm_flmg_act_34), [The World's Fastest Indian](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0412080/?ref_=nm_flmg_act_32),